# .htaccess 301 Redirect non slash domains and slash domain to .html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, slash

I am trying to add some code to my .htaccess to redirect  slash and non slash urls to the .html all url's apart from my homepage.

For example 
www.mydomain.com/cat/ and www.mydomain.com/cat 
should redirect to www.mydomain.com/cat.html

I have managed to add the following to my .htaccess which redirects www.mydomain.com/cat to the right place www.mydomain.com/cat.html but need some help on how to make slash version redirect to the .html page

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

My whole .htaccess looks like this, if anyone has any suggestions on how it should look in light of the above it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxx.xxx.xxx.xx [nc,or]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L] 


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/$1.html [R=301,L]


DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
# Pleas note that RewriteBase setting is obsolete use it only in case you experience  some problems with SEO addon.
# Some hostings require RewriteBase to be uncommented
# Example:
# Your store url is http://www.yourcompany.com/store/cart
# So "RewriteBase" should be:
# RewriteBase /store/cart
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(png|gif|ico|swf|jpe?g|js|css)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php?sef_rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

SOLVED:
I just added:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$  /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The separate rules seems to be working for you, but I think you can simplify it to one rule, with an optional slash. Your rule redirects the slash to no-slash, which then redirects again to the .html. With one rule, you'd only have one redirect.

This has the standard RewriteCond that check if it's not a file or a folder, so it doesn't keep redirecting .html if it's already one. Then, the `\?` in the ReweriteRule is an optional slash.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://mydomain.com/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

If this is all in your domain, you can omit it from the result:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Also, note this will catch and work with subfolders, whether or not you mean it to. e.g., 
www.mydomain.com/animals/cat/ will redirect to www.mydomain.com/animals/cat.html